# Extracting certain rows from a text file, skipping others

Tags: perl, awk, grep

I have a file that contains a long list of data like this:

```
b09   fl__2220  fuel20       ddm___an  ddm___an  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de
                 fl           dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  ddm___an  ddm___an
       simulated     32.9       0.0000    0.0000    0.0659    0.0888    0.1132    0.1298    0.1374    0.1413    0.1452
                                0.1460    0.1434    0.1404    0.1339    0.1186    0.0946    0.0708    0.0000    0.0000
       measured      29.0       0.0000    0.0000    0.0579    0.0780    0.0994    0.1140    0.1207    0.1241    0.1276
                                0.1283    0.1260    0.1233    0.1177    0.1042    0.0831    0.0622    0.0000    0.0000
```

I want to extract certain data from a particular row, and then more data from a few rows ahead.  From the first row I want to extract 'b09 fl__2220'  and then I want to extract the fifth and sixth rows, so everything after 'measured'.  The final output would look something like this:

```
b09   fl__2220  measured      29.0       0.0000    0.0000    0.0579    0.0780    0.0994    0.1140    0.1207    0.1241    0.1276 0.1283    0.1260    0.1233    0.1177    0.1042    0.0831    0.0622    0.0000    0.0000
```

I can get gawk to extract the b09 and fl__2220 with `gawk '/fl__2220/ {print $1, $2}'`, but how do I get it to skip ahead and read the stuff from 'measured' line onwards to the last 0.0000? Or would something like perl or grep be better for situations like this?

The whole file contains similar data, eg. 'c12   fl__2211. . .', etc.  But I just want the data for b09  fl__2220.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to do in Perl.  It looks like your data is fixed width so in that case you would parse it with an `unpack` template.

Here is the documentation.

1. [pack tutorial](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut)
2. https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack
3. https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack

```perl
$line =
"b09   fl__2220  fuel20       ddm___an  ddm___an  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de  dfl___de";
@fields = unpack "A6A10";

###
### produces @fields containing ("b09", "fl__2220")
###
```

You would write the template for each type of line and extract it in the same manner.  The `A` template character automatically trims trailing spaces.  The number after `A` means how many of that type to take.  `A6` means take 6 characters and trim.

Another way to do it would be to use `substr` to pull out a number of substrings but you have to trim it yourself.  `unpack` is usually easier.

If you are new to Perl remember to always put `use strict;` and `use diagnostics;` at the top of your script.  That way you'll get a nice explanatory message whenever anything goes wrong instead of hopelessness!

HTH

Comment: My Perl knowledge isn't that great, so let me see if I understand your solution.  

I would have a variable $line that would contain the first row of data.  Then a second variable, let's say $line2 that would contain the row starting with 'measured' and all the numbers that follow it?  What about the last row, where it's all just numbers? 

And then @fields = unpack prints the fields from each row that I want to print?

Comment: In real code you would have all the lines in an array so that you can do the line number math.  You would have seperate `unpack` templates for each type of data you want to extract and use it based on the line number offset.  Here is a tutorials link to help you get started. https://perldoc.perl.org/perl#Tutorials